# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting when inserting data into db

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert data into a db that is obtained from an API. I have used this previously without issue, and can't see what has changed for it to stop working. All fields are text fields except 'id', 'multiplier' and 'price', the first of which is handled by postgres.

I've ensured the number of format placeholders map the number of fields and that the query should be correct, so I can't see what the issue is.

**Other answers to similar problems mentioned mixing string formatting, which is not the case here.**

My code:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO "public"."main_page_product" ("id","collection_name","description",
"multiplier","dimension","feat1","feat10","feat2","feat3",
"feat4","feat5","feat6","feat7","feat8","feat9","image_url",
"price","short_name","sku","meta_name")VALUES (nextval('catalogue_product_id_seq'::regclass),%s,%s,
'2.2',%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
 (temp1['name'], temp1['short_description'], temp1['dimension'],
 temp1['feat1'], temp1['feat2'], temp1['feat3'], temp1['feat4'],
 temp1['feat5'], temp1['feat6'], temp1['feat7'], temp1['feat8'],
 temp1['feat9'], temp1['feat10'], finurl, temp1['price'],
 temp1['short_name'], temp1['sku'], temp1['meta_title']))
```

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: That is a *looooooooooooooong* line of code. :) Can you please multiline that?

Comment: @EthanK Sorry, done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mismatch between column-names and params:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."main_page_product" 
("id","collection_name","description","multiplier",    # 4
 "dimension","feat1","feat10","feat2",                 # 4
 "feat3","feat4","feat5","feat6",                      # 4
 "feat7","feat8","feat9","image_url",                  # 4
 "price","short_name","sku","meta_name")               # 4

 VALUES 

(nextval('catalogue_product_id_seq'::regclass),%s,%s,'2.2',  # 4
%s,%s,%s,%s,                                                 # 4
%s,%s,%s,%s,                                                 # 4
%s,%s,%s,%s,                                                 # 4
%s,%s,%s)""",                                                # 3
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot, I must have counted at least 10 times, and yet your formatting makes it so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: @JakeRankin happens :) take a break, get some fresh air and some coffee (or some sleep depending on how tired you are ;o)

Comment: i want to take a picture of this code and hang it on a wall somewhere. This looks like art now.